# Outer Join Based On Concatenated SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation, outer-join

SO perhaps the data framework is flawed from the start, but.. I need to do an out join on two tables, but I need to do it based a concatenation of 2 column sin the second table.

For instance, table one

```
title  |  key
-------+-------
foo    | Bar1
```

table two

```
subcat  | pt1 | pt2
--------+-----+-----
kitty   | Bar | 1
```

I basically need to use `pt1`+`pt2` combined as the foreign key.

This is largely academic as I can add a column to the dataset (not my original creation) that is the concatenation, however, I wanted to know if the was possible.

Postgres version 8.4.8

cheers.bo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join condition can be pretty much any expression; in particular, you can include string concatenation:

```
select ...
from t1 left outer join t2 on t1.key = t2.pt1 || t2.pt2
where ...
```

Comment: `t2.pt1 || t2.pt2` wouldnt that match either `Bar` or `1`?

Comment: @roberthuttinger: No, `||` is the standard SQL string concatenation operator, not a logical-or: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a sub query and perform the join against the sub query:

```
SELECT t1.foo, t1.key, t3.subcat FROM table1
JOIN (SELECT t2.pt1 || t2.pt2 AS ptjoined, t2.subcat 
      FROM tabletwo AS t2) as t3
ON t3.ptjoined = t1.key
```

Comment: I was thinking along these lines as well... concatenation is much more direct. thanks!